# load Python Pickle (.pkl) file

Tags: python, file, pickle

I am trying to load .pkl files that are in the same directory where my .py file is located. The following is my code:

```
import os

def load_var(var_name):
    fid = open(os.path.join((var_name, '.pkl')))
    data = pickle.load(fid)
    fid.close()
    return data

def main():
    data = load_var('myfilename')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I keep on running into the error:

```
fid = open(os.path.join((var_name, '.pkl')))
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, tuple found
```

Is there an easy way to resolve this error?

Answer (score 1):

The input to `os.path.join` should not be a tuple. That is, the command should read:

```
fid = open(os.path.join(var_name, '.pkl'))
```

Answer (score 0):

c. leather is correct. Remove the extra brackets ().
Also note that you are using os.path.join() on what seems to be filename and extension?

The output of that would be var_name/.pkl, not sure if that is what you are expecting.

```
>>> filename = "mytestfile"
>>> mypath = os.path.join(filename, ".pkl")
>>> 
>>> print mypath
mytestfile/.pkl
```